# Generate insert column based on select columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a scenario, where 100's of select statements sql's are in one metadata table or some text file.

Need to insert all sql results into one specific table. (master table has col1, col2,col3 .... 200columns )

problem im facing(ORA-00947) is every select statement has different number of columns.
.. i need to generate INSERT PART.

```
CASE 1 : INSERT INTO (COL1,COL2,COL3) <<this select part comes from file/variable>>

CASE 2 : INSERT INTO (COL1) <<this select part comes from file/variable>>

CASE 3 : INSERT INTO (COL1) <<this select part comes from file/variable>>
```

have to figure out how many columns are in select part then generate INSERT part. 
.

Thought of create as select but problem is some select statement has max(col) without  alias so it will fail.

Comment: Dynamic queries might be a good place to start.  If this was SQL Server, I'd be able to answer, but I'm not as familiar with Oracle.  Link to the Oracle docs is here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: This is not a technical problem, it is a political problem. You need to push back on the requirements. Nobody cannot write a robust solution to process the `<<this select part comes from file/variable>>` unless it comes with the correct metadata for each select so we can assemble the dynamic SQL correctly.

Comment: Thanks Laks.  How would one know what column of the `master table` should receive `max(col)` if there is no matched column alias?  Does the `master table` have some reliable way to translate, for example `max(col)` => MAX_COL or something?

Comment: Master table don't have any matching name, it just has col1,col2.....etc.   I no need to worry abt what data comes in. I just need to insert in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

If you are storing SQL in a table, then you are constructing your query dynamically.  So, update the table and list the columns that you want.

You could then construct the `insert`s as :

```
insert into master_table (<column list here>)
    <select here>;
```

*Both* the `select` and column list would come from the table.

Comment: Finding the columns for those 100's of SQL is the probem

Comment: @Laks . . . Why?  You have all the SQL in a single table.  It is not like you have to search for it somewhere.

Comment: Sql's are in table , have to loop through all Sql's , execute n insert result to master table.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest is to create a view for each SELECT statement. Then you can query the USER_TAB_COLUMNS view on the view name and get the column names.

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: Thought of creating views dynamically but same problem, some select statement has max(col) without alias so it will fail

Comment: @laks - it appears whoever is specifying your requirements has failed to understand the difference between **programming** and **magic**. You can solve this problem with dynamic SQL provided your input file contains the metadata necessary to interpret the select statements. But to distinguish between statements which contain `COL1,COL2,COL3` and ones which contain `MAX(COL)` you're going to have to write something which parses those statements. It's possible but tricky (and probably brittle).